# Sum all the Timespan per row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, timespan

This is my front end, in my case, I would like to add all the total hours of time in and time out of all my rows in my datagridview. My datagridview fields are id, employee code, date, timein and timeout.

[image]

Here is my back end, in here I computed the the late, the total hours, the day difference and the night difference. Is it possible to display on my textboxes the total hours, the late, the day diff and night based on the data on my datagridview. Sorry for my english, clarify my questions with yours.

```
string timeIn = datagridAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells["timeIn"].Value.ToString();
string timeOut = datagridAttendance.CurrentRow.Cells["timeOut"].Value.ToString();
DateTime tIn = Convert.ToDateTime(timeIn);
DateTime tOut = Convert.ToDateTime(timeOut);
TimeSpan span = tOut - tIn;
txtTotalHours.Text = Convert.ToString(span);
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
txtMe.Text = tIn.ToShortTimeString();
DateTime inTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtMe.Text);
if (inTime > start)
{
    TimeSpan late = inTime - start;
    txtLate.Text = Convert.ToString(late);
}
else
{
    txtLate.Text = "Not Late";
}
TimeSpan passLength = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
TimeSpan nightTime = new TimeSpan();
while (tIn < tOut)
{
    tIn = tIn.Add(passLength);
    if (tIn.Hour < 6 || tIn.Hour == 23)
    {
        nightTime = nightTime.Add(passLength);
    }
}

txtNightDif.Text = Convert.ToString(nightTime);
TimeSpan day = span - nightTime;
txtDayDif.Text = Convert.ToString(day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like below with the arrays timein[] timeout[] being the values in each row of DataGridView

```
            DateTime[] timein = { DateTime.Parse("1:00"), DateTime.Parse("3:00"), DateTime.Parse("5:00"), DateTime.Parse("7:00") };
            DateTime[] timeout = { DateTime.Parse("2:00"), DateTime.Parse("4:00"), DateTime.Parse("6:00"), DateTime.Parse("8:00") };

            TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();

            for (int i = 0; i < timein.Count(); i++)
            {
                totalTime += timeout[i] - timein[i];
            }​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your database, and then return the sum of timespans as a column. That would be better and far easier.

Comment: for timespan only it is possible, however, computing the day diff and night diff wouldn't be possible for this case.